# How to change component with Sidebar material-ui React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, drawer

im using React and i am new.I use Drawer, but I don't know how to display the desired component by clicking on each button. You can see the Drawer code here

```
export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
              [classes.hide]: open
            })}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Mini variant drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open
          })
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {routes.map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to click each button to run the desired component. The components are located in the ./src path. Thank you very much for editing my code from [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-rain-ft2zk?file=/pages/demo.js) for a deep understanding of the subject

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router renders blank page after import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724167/react-router-renders-blank-page-after-import)