# React router renders blank page after import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I am trying to create a sidebar having links to different pages or modules. I have everything modularized meaning, the sidebar Navigation is a separate module where I import all the linked classes and then use **react-router-dom** to redirect the paths. But somehow when redirecting, The response page is blank.

**Navigation Module:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Colors from "../../pages/Colors";
import Typography from "../../pages/Typography";
import Spaces from "../../pages/Spaces";
import Buttons from "../../pages/Buttons";
import Inputs from "../../pages/Inputs";
import Grid from "../../pages/Grid";

import "./style.css";

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/colors">Colors</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/typography">Typography</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/spaces">Spaces</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/buttons">Buttons</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/inputs">Inputs</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/grid">Grid</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/colors" component={Colors} exact />
          <Route path="/typography" component={Typography} exact />
          <Route path="/spaces" component={Spaces} exact />
          <Route path="/buttons" component={Buttons} exact />
          <Route path="/inputs" component={Inputs} exact />
          <Route path="/grid" component={Grid} exact />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

Now the link classes that I import here have just simple content right now like the following.

**pages/Colors/index.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Colors extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Colors</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Colors;
```

The main **BrowserRouter** is located in the **App.js** component from where the **Sidebar** component is called having **Navigation** component.

Now the thing is if I remove the **BrowserRouter** from **App.js** and put it in the **Navigation** module the routing works.

How come so?

Which pattern is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with `React-router` and `React-router-dom`, make sure the `Router` component is the top most parent.
You can try again by:

- Move all `Router`, `Switch` into `App.js`.
- Inside `Sidebar` component, just render links, neither `Switch` nor `Route` component.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer from Shina, who covers it pretty well, just a few more comments. Keeping your `React-Router` and switch in your `App.jsx` file is relatively standard. Since App is the parent component, the `Router` and `Switch` will only be rendered once, while keeping the router in `Nav.jsx` would force the `Switch` re-rendered with each route. But keeping the `Switch` wrapped in the `Router` component should solve your issues here.